# Handling imbalanced data with partial_fit and OneVsRestClassifier

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, weighted, multiclass-classification

Simply put, I have an imbalanced data set and I have to train using `partial_fit` because of the size. Some of the methods I use can't naturally handle multiclass problems, so I am wrapping them with a `OneVsRestClassifier`. However, this causes problems adjusting the `class_weights`.

Because I use `partial_fit` the option of setting `class_weight='balanced'` or `'auto'` is not possible.

Is there a simple solution where I can use `OneVsRestClassifier` and still weight my classes?

Example code:

```
model = OneVsRestClassifier(SGDClassifier(loss='log', alpha=1e-4, penalty='elasticnet', class_weight=weights))
model.partial_fit(features, labels_i, classes=np.unique(labels_i))
```

where `weights` is a dictionary containing the weights for each class.

Comment: You could upsample your minority class or set `sample_weight` in the `partial_fit` to reflect your class imbalance.

Comment: Also you don't need to wrap most of the classifiers in `OneVsRestClassifier` it's handled implicitly by `sklearn`.

Comment: Adding to @ncfirth 's comment, please see here to know how scikit handles multi-class and multi-label problems implicitly :- http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html

Comment: @ncfirth In my case I need `OneVsRestClassifier`, as I use the methods `SGDClassifier`, `Perceptron` and `PassiveAggressiveClassifier` that all three are listed as multiclass together with `OneVsRestClassifier`. I have chosen these as they can handle sparse matrices and has `partial_fit`. 
Also, `sample_weight` is only working if `class_weight` has been set, which I am unable to do because of `OneVsRestClassifier`.
I was mostly looking for an option not using oversampling, or something I can use together with it, as I would have to upsample 1000x, or more, for some classes.

Comment: Thats what @ncfirth is saying. You dont need to wrap. Its written on the page I posted above, that they will handle multiclass situation by using `ovr` strategy internally. No need for you to do it.